# Natural combinatorial property in Natural Proofs

Tags: complexity-theory, p-vs-np

From [Natual Proofs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_proof)

> Specifically, natural proofs prove lower bounds on the circuit complexity of boolean functions. A natural proof shows, either directly or indirectly, that a boolean function has a certain ***natural combinatorial property***.

I haven't read the mentioned paper. Can somebody explain what is meant by "natural combinatorial property"? What ***is*** that property, and what is *natural* about it?

Answer (score 2):

From the paper [[1](https://doi.org/10.1006%2Fjcss.1997.1494)]:

> We start by defining what we mean by a "natural combinatorial property"; natural proofs will be those that use a natural combinatorial property.
>
> Formally, by a combinatorial property of Boolean functions we will mean a set of Boolean functions $\{ C_n \subseteq F_n | n\in \omega\}$. Thus, a Boolean function $f_n$ will possess property $C_n$ if and only if $f_n \in C_n$. (Alternatively, we will sometimes find it convenient to use function notation: $C_n(f_n)= 1$ if $f_n \in C_n$; and $C_n(f_n) = 0$ if $f_n \notin C_n$.) The combinatorial property $C_n$ is *natural* if it contains a subset $C^*_n$ with the following two conditions:
>
> *Constructivity*. The predicate $f_n \stackrel{?}{\in} C^*_n$ is in $P$. Thus $C^*_n$ is computable in time which is polynomial in the truth table of $f_n$;
>
> *Largeness*. $|C^*_n| \geq 2^{-O(n)} \cdot |F_n|$.

Further discussion continues later:

> The definitions of natural property and natural proof can
> be explained much less formally. First, a proof that some
> explicit function $\{ g_n \}$ does not have polynomial-sized circuits must plainly identify some combinatorial property $C_n$
> of $g_n$ that is *used* in the proof. That is, the proof will show
> that all functions $f_n$ that have this property, including $g_n$
> itself, are hard to compute. In other words, $C_n$ is *useful*. If
> $\{ g_n \} \in NP$; then the proof concludes $P\neq NP$. Our main
> contention, backed by evidence in the next section, is that
> current proof techniques would strongly tend to make this
> $C_n$ *large* and *constructive* as defined above. (Or at least these
> two conditions would hold for some subproperty $C^*_n$ of $C_n$.)
>
> In order to understand the definition of *large* more
> intuitively, let $N=2^n$. Largeness requires that $|C^*_n|/|F_n | \geq
> 1/{N^k}$ for some fixed $k>0$; i.e., $f_n$ has a nonnegligible chance
> of having property $C_n$.
>
> *Constructively* is a more subtle notion to understand and
> justify. We take as our basic benchmark of "constructive"
> that $f_n \in C_n$ be decidable in time $2^{O(n)}$ , i.e., polynomial as a
> function of $2^n$. Now, this is exponential in the number $n$ of
> variables in $f_n$ , and this makes our concept somewhat
> mysterious, especially since we are going to employ it for
> studying computations which are polynomial in $n$! The best
> justification we have is empirical: the vast majority of
> properties of Boolean functions or $n$-vertex graphs (etc.)
> that one encounters in combinatorics are at worst exponential-time decidable, and, as a matter of fact, known lower
> bounds proofs operate only with such properties. It also
> should be noted that, even with this loose notion of constructivity, we manage to prove in Section 4 strong negative
> results on the nonexistence of natural proofs.

1. Razborov, Alexander A., and Steven Rudich. "[Natural proofs.](https://doi.org/10.1006%2Fjcss.1997.1494)" Proceedings of the twenty-sixth annual ACM symposium on Theory of computing. 1994.